# Could Closures in JavaScript be Considered as Behaving Like Sub-Objects?

Tags: javascript, closures

I'm currently looking at what closure are and how they work, and the best way in my mind to see a closure is essentially as sub-object, i.e. a part, or child of the parent object.

A closure is a function that lives within another function, and what this means is that this child function can be returned by the parent function, just like other things in the parent function.

The problem with returning a function is that it was created within the scope of its parent object, and because of this it may need to have access to certain resources of the things in its scope.

When something is passed by reference out of a function (i.e. an object), it cannot be deleted until there is no reference left in the code for it.

When garbage collection happens it looks through the things left in memory, and anything that is not needed will be marked and effectively deleted, and so free up memory space. Anything that is needed by the closure, like code, internal vars, parent vars, params etc. (things in scope that the function says it needs), are left there. When these things are no longer needed, then at some point later it will by marked and deleted by the garbage collector.

So essentially closures are sub-objects that contain the returned function and the things it needs from its scope to work, and the rest of the parent object will be deleted as there is no reference/need for it. Finally, at some point later, when code no longer needs the sub-object/closure, it is effectively marked as not referenced, and removed from memory.

Does this sound roughly/conceptually right?

Comment: This question might be better suited to computer science exchange: https://cs.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that's roughly right, with one slight change. Don't think of it as a sub-object. Think of it as just an object, but one that can capture that which it needs.  Exactly like you said, if a closure is defined within the scope of one function, and it uses local members from that function, then the closure 'captures' those values, essentially like adding other owners to it.  It's something that trips a lot of people up when dealing with counters and such, not realizing they're carrying around 'escaped' local instances of variables from other functions.

But again, overall, your general understanding is pretty much right-on.

Comment: Hey @MarqueIV . Thanks for your input!:) I like the notion of 'escaped' local instances of variables, maybe they should be called 'rogue';) Closures by all accounts look to be a blessing if you know how to use  them, and may a bit of a curse if you don't;) Thanks again, always good to have a second opinion on these things.

Comment: No problem!  Just remember... in its simplest description, a closure is nothing more than a function (well, the signature and 'guts' of a function if you will) that you can store in a variable or pass as an argument, then refer to it by or call it from that variable/argument the same way you'd call any other named function.  Heck... you can also pass a named function to a place that's expecting a closure so long as they have the same signature.  They're really helpful/powerful things without the drawbacks of a C++ function pointer.